# Puma gem not found when deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3, puma

I want to deploy my application with Capistrano and Puma to a VPS, but every time I get this error:

```
INFO [17b91266] Running RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.4 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec puma -C /home/deploy/applications/app/shared/puma.rb --daemon as deploy@11.111.11.11
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@11.111.11.11: Exception while executing as deploy@11.111.11.11: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: bundler: command not found: puma
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'puma'
group :production do
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
end
```

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/puma'
```

## Update:

Solved the problem. I didn't update branch "master" with the last changes.

Comment: Looks like you need to run `rbenv rehash` on your server, that's why it can't find the puma executable

Comment: @Joeman29 you should make this an answer. You are probably right.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to run `rbenv rehash` on your server, that's why it can't find the puma executable

Comment: I did `rbenv rehash` on server but it didn't help